# How to limit number of participant less than 10 for a single transaction?

Tags: civievent

Scenario is like this:

- Total Participant for the event is 500 (I know how to define that)
- 2 types of ticket available: Adult & child
- On a single transaction only 5 people should be able to register, mix and match of adult & child. (But when I
  select "multiple participant is allowed", CiviCRM automatically enables
  10 participants).

Is it something possible to do to decrease number of participant value to less than 10?

Answer (score 3):

This function is added to CiviCRM core 4.7. But I have managed to get it done by this extension
https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.maxadditionalparticipants

Comment: excellent solution!